# Associação belongs_to dentro de serializer não está retornando nada

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

A aplicação contem um modulo chamado `Dispute`, este modulo contem `Procedures`, cada `Procedure` contem um usuário e pertence a uma disputa.

Como está descrito abaixo, `belongs_to` não é exibido e o atributo `:user` é chamado para retornar o usuário (porem sem a aplicação do serializer).

```
class Dispute::ProceduresSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :user

  # FIXME: Not working with belongs_to. Called attribute instead.
  # belongs_to :user, serializer: Dispute::UserSerializer
end

class DisputeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id

  has_many :procedures, serializer: Dispute::ProceduresSerializer
end
```

Abaixo descrevo as associações:

```
class Dispute::Procedure < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :dispute
  belongs_to :user
end

class Dispute < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :procedures, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :procedures, dependent: :destroy
  ...
end
```

Analisando o código acima tem alguma ideia de onde está o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que, por padrão, o [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) somente apresenta um nível no serializer. É necessário adicionar ao arquivo `active_model_serializers.rb` em `config/initializers` a configuração para mais de 1 nível (cada * é um nível):

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.default_includes = '**'
```

Está configuração foi adicionada [neste pull request](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/pull/1426).